# Importing 3 languages ( English, Arabic and Urdu) data in MySql from Excel sheet, using UTF-8 in PhP

Tags: mysql, excel, utf-8, arabic, urdu

I have a sheet in Excel having characters from different languages in different columns.  Basic English, then translations in other columns of Excel Sheet.

Data size is more than 500 characters in few cases.

Want to put it in my Sql database file. 
I was using NaviCat ( trial version) to import data from Excel to MySql database.  Faced following issues:- 
   1.  Data is truncated 
   2.  Used  varChar 255 ,  in Sql table Field with UTF-8 encoding
   3.  Changed to Medium Text  ,  still complete data not imported.

**Answer** 
        ....   Solution proposed has worked for me. Thank you.     ...    **Open Office SpreadSheet is better solution for importing data in sql**

*Leaving it as it may help someone else.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I don't want the information thrown away.  And there is a thorough Answer to the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Saad, it appears that you want to use few tools or open source software to handle this without coding.

I solved a similar issue , in few steps :-

1. Open Excel file in Open Office Calc ( open source free software)
2. Convert file / work sheet into  open office spreadsheet.ods   , using Save As option.
3. http://localhost/phpmyadmin , Go to phpMyAdmin  if Using XAMPP on Windows 
   4   Select your database ,   click import option
4. Change import format to .ods  ,  by the way,  even if you only select the open office file, import option will be automatically set to .ods
5. Import Data

Following issues were solved in my case : -

Length of data 
  Automatic adjustment of table design ,  from VarChar to  Text etc

Note : 
          UTF-8  encoding be changed to UTF8mb4  encoding
          Collation be set to uutf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

I faced lot of trouble in adjusting to data cell in each chunk,   I changed MySql   my.ini file

max_allowed_packet=128M   //  from 1 MB to 128

and

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600  // from 50  to 600

Note

character-set-server=utf8mb4

Complete file  my.ini  is appended as under

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# c:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is c:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="c:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="c:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="c:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="c:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="c:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=128M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="c:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "c:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="c:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="c:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "c:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="c:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=256M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

Comment: Open Office Work around to import data in to phpMyAdmin worked for me.  Thanks